# How to get Pundit to apply a scope to a model with a different name than the policy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I have a DirectoryController, and -- deliberately -- no UsersController.  UsersController will doubtless be added when I create the administration controls, and will have a totally difference scope & purpose.

When I call policy_scoped in the directory controller, I want to use the scope from DirectoryPolicy and not UserPolicy (which doesn't exist yet).  I want to do it in a way that verify_policy_scoped recognizes, which means the obvious work around of `DirectoryPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, User).resolve` is not only a tad long but also actually doesn't work.  (Which seems like a bug)  This seems like such an obvious oversight that I'm sure there's something, somewhere, to make this work, I just don't know what.

How do I do this in Pundit?

Comment: Policies are coupled to models. So you usually create one policy class per model. In your case it would make sense to create a `UserPolicy` class right now and not later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
DirectoryPolicy::Scope.new(current_user, User).resolve
```

you're effectively bypassing pundit's `policy_scoped?` tracking.

My first thought is that if `DirectoryPolicy::Scope` is intended to scope your user data, maybe you need to create a `Directory` model as pundit expects. It could be as simple as this

```
class Directory < User; end
```

Now when you have something like this in your `DirectoryController`

```
@users = policy_scope(Directory)
```

pundit can properly infer you want the `DirectoryPolicy::Scope`, and your `resolve` method can treat the `scope` as if it were the `User` class because of the inheritance.

If you can't subclass `User` as I describe here you'll need to show some actual code from your app and provide more context as to what `Directory` is and what you're trying to do with it.